# Importing local HTML page with fetch into another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, fetch, web-component

Basically, I have a html file called `panel` containing a simple DIV that I would like to insert into another main HTML file.

Instead of using web components, I'd like to implement a simple solution as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54471296/1979665).

So, here is what I am doing for testing (just logging the panel to console):

**panel.html**

```
<div id="panel">
    <h1>It works...</h1>
</div>
```

**get-template.ts**

```
export async function getTemplate(filepath: string, selectors: string) {
    let response = await fetch(filepath);
    let txt = await response.text();

    let html =  new DOMParser().parseFromString(txt, 'text/html');

    return html.querySelector(selectors);
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { getTemplate } from './get-template'

getTemplate('/path/to/panel.html','#panel').then((panel) => {console.log(panel);})
```

The console logs "null".

If this info could make any difference, I am using parcel-bundler to build the application.

Comment: By “local”, do you mean that you are testing this by loading the main HTML document in your browser via the _file system_, or do you have a proper local web server set-up, and are loading them via HTTP(S)? It needs to be the latter, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007055/fetch-request-to-local-file-not-working

Comment: Everything is tested using parcel. The panel.html is  referenced with a local path inside the first getTemplate parameter.

Comment: _“Everything is tested using parcel.”_ - I don’t know what that is, therefor not what this means in regard to whether you are actually testing via HTTP or not, either.

Comment: Yes it means I have a localhost which serves all my built source files via HTTP. I am only fetching panel.html through its local path (non HTTP, my computer path). I think this would be possible, isn't it?

Comment: If you load the main document via HTTP, then `/path/to/panel.html` automatically resolves to an absolute HTTP URL as well. _Is_ that the actual path value you are using, or is it something else, that deliberately tries to access this via the file system?

Comment: The actual value I am using is '/home/umberto/myapp/src/panel/panel.html' The idea is that in my app, panel.html is only used to separate this part of what will be the main HTML. So I am fetching it hoping to retrieve it as a `HTMLElement` with my `getTemplate` function (that's what [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is supposed to return when used successfully), and then place it with JS somewhere inside my main HTML. At the moment, I am just testing if I can get the HTMLElement, but in the console I just log a `null` value.

Comment: Comsole doesn’t say anything else, errors/warnings? What do you see, when you inspect the actual request in the network panel?

Comment: I think you pointed me to the right direction, thanks! The network panel reads 200 OK for the panel.html resource, but its URL became 'localhost:1234/home/umberto/myapp/src/panel/panel.html' which does not exists. I wonder if this is simply due to how parcel builds my app, or if it would happen anyway...

Comment: So you are accessing your main document via `http://localhost:1234`? Then this is simply how relative URLs _work_. What did you _expect_ where `/home/umberto/myapp/src/panel/panel.html` should refer to?

Comment: Yeah, localhost:1234 points to the `dist` dir that is created b parcel when it builds my app. If I copy and paste panel.html in the `dist` directory and refer to it in my code with a relative URL like `getTemplate('./panel.html')` the code works. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: _What did you expect where /home/umberto/myapp/src/panel/panel.html should refer to?_ At the beginning of my test, i tried with a relative path and failed. Actually, as I said in my previous comment, it's a matter of using relative paths but having in mind it has to be relative to the dist folder created when parcel builds the app. I don't think this was a question worth downvotes, but this is just my opinion and I can live with that. Thanks for helping me out, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was determined by **@CBroe** and was about the fact that when `parcel` builds my application, the file path of my `panel.html` resource changes to be relative to the built `dist` folder.

Just to clarify:

- before building the path is relative to the `main.ts` file
- after building the path is relative to the `dist` folder

So the solution is to think about the final URL the `panel.html` will have, and refer to it in advance before building with parcel.

Something like this would work in my case:

**main.ts (new)**

```
import { getTemplate } from './get-template'

getTemplate('./panel.html','#panel').then((panel) => {console.log(panel);})
```

Then of course, the other step will be to copy the actual `panel.hml` file into the `dist` directory, otherwise the URL will point to a non existing file.

I see there was a [github issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1411) about automatically copy static (or assets) files in the parcel repository, and one of the solution provided is to use the plugin [`parcel-plugin-static-files-copy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy).